# Not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, iframe-resizer

I've set up the script on [this](https://www.castleveterinarygroup.co.uk/veterinary-care-for-pets-launceston/castle-care-club-pet-club-gives-great-value-and-real-savings/) page. The sign-up form at the bottom.

**Problem:**

On mobile the page shrinks quite a bit on the third page of the form, 
**however the iframe stays the same so the user is left with a big blank space**.

How to get it working on mobile? I'm testing in chrome on android at the moment.

Open to all suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the edits.. any idea of a resolution though?

Comment: It is most likely an issue with you CSS

Comment: @DavidBradshaw It's odd as it works on desktop ok? What do you think could be causing it not to work on mobile?

Comment: Could be anything in your css, delete large chunks of it until the problem goes away and then add stuff back slowly